# SQL Query Semantics Error only on some log files

Tags: sql, xml, logparser

I have exported a Log Parser Query into a Powershell script and I get the following error every time I try and run the query on *some* logs but not all.

```
Error parsing query: WHERE clause: Semantic Error: content contains a 
STRING value ("username") which cannot be parsed by the input context: 
Value "username" is not an 
integer [SQL query syntax invalid or unsupported.]
```

I have compared both of the log files that I ran the query on and the event inside is exactly the same, so I am unsure as to why I would get the error on one and not the other. Below is the query which I am running.

```
SELECT /log/event/@time, /log/event/session/@windowsAccount, /log/event/session/@virtualAccount  
INTO '" + $Destination + "' 
FROM C:\Users\my.name\Desktop\Logs4\*.log 
WHERE /log/event/session/@virtualAccount='username' AND /log/event/@name = 'I_LOGON_AUTH_SUCCEEDED'
```

The expected result is that I grab the logon time, and account name of a certain account and export it all to a CSV file. This isn't happening however due to the script stopping upon throwing the above error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that those documents contain values for the "virtualAccount" attribute that only contain integers, hence LogParser guesses their type as `integer` rather than `string`. You can verify this with the following command, and checking what's the type deduced for that field:

```
LogParser -h -i:xml mylog.xml
```

Unfortunately there's no easy workaround, other than trying to parse multiple XML files at once, in which case LogParser will hopefully use the most forgiving type.